# Threading multiple methods within a class in Python

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading

I'd like to use threading to run multiple methods at the same time. However, when I run the following code only testFunc1 executes. The string "test2" is never printed even once and I'm not sure why. I'd like both testFunc1 and testFunc2 to be executing at the same time. I'm very new to threading and Python in general, so any advice to regarding threading is welcome along with a solution to my problem. Here is the code:

```
import time, threading

class testClass:

    def __init__(self):
        self.count = 0

    def testFunc1(self):
        while True:
            print(self.count)
            self.count = self.count + 1
            time.sleep(1)

    def testFunc2(self):
        while True:
            print("test2")
            time.sleep(1)

    def run(self):
        threading.Thread(target=self.testFunc1(), args=(self,)).start()
        threading.Thread(target=self.testFunc2(), args=(self,)).start()

test = testClass()

test.run()
```

Comment: TYPO: change to `threading.Thread(target=self.testFunc1, args=(self,)).start()` and `threading.Thread(target=self.testFunc2, args=(self,)).start()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you pass a method by `self.method`/`cls_object.method` then `self` is passed automatically, You only need to pass `self` manually in case you pass the function by `testClass.testFunc2` (in your case `method` is `testFunc2`), so `args=(self,)` is redundant.

Furthermore, you don't need to add `()` when you pass the function because you don't want to call that function but just pass its reference, hence you can fix your code to:

```py
threading.Thread(target=self.testFunc1).start()
threading.Thread(target=self.testFunc2).start()
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to make following changes inside `run()` method.

```
threading.Thread(target=self.testFunc1, args=[]).start()
threading.Thread(target=self.testFunc2, args=[]).start()
```

Basically while invoking a function inside a thread, you don't need to use `()` along with the function call.

so instead of using `self.testFunc1()` you need to specify `self.testFunc1` in the `target`.

Since `testFunc1` & `testFunc2` not taking any arguments, `args` can be passed as an empty list. .